# HandWritten notes with finger gesture recognization

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I want to create Notebook  app that allows user to create handwritten notes with pen or pencil image ..I know some methods for single touch ,double touch and swipe. But need some directions to make this type of app..Means how could I draw letters on swipe..

please give me suggestions or any directions ??
links?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's quite a general question you're asking. You already know how to use the touch events, so where are you having problems?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for help about drawing - have a look at the [Graphics and Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html).

Welcome to Stack Overflow where specific question will give you specific answers.